# ASP.NET MVC list pull rendering technique

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, rendering

Hy,
i went from this page on internet http://studiostyles.info/schemes that have a particular rendering technique, the list grow when the page is rendered. Is there anyone that can explain me how it is possible?
Thanks in advance.
F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery: http://www.beyondcoding.com/2009/01/15/release-jquery-plugin-endless-scroll/